# How to return a struct without using global declaration of struct in C

Tags: c, struct, return, return-value

Hello i am trying to return a struct from a function but i cant find a way to do so without declaring the struct as global. How can this be done? Here is the code (THIS WORKS AS IT IS)

```
...
void log_in();
struct node
{
    char name_log[20];
    int passlog;
    int user_point;
}tmp;

int main()
{
  ...
  else if(sel=='2')
  {
     log_in();
     if (tmp.passlog==TRUE)
     logged_in(tmp.name_log,tmp.user_point);  //and here i want to use the retun values
  }

void log_in()
{
   ... //make the changes in the struct
}
...
```

What i want to achieve is to place the struct node declaration within main but sadly it wont work. So here is what i am trying to do: (THIS DOESN'T WORK)

```
...
struct node log_in();

int main() {
    ...
    else if(sel=='2') {
        struct node //here is where i want to declare
        {
            char name_log[20];
            int passlog;
            int user_point;
        }tmp;

        log_in();
        if (tmp.passlog==TRUE)
            logged_in(tmp.name_log,tmp.user_point); //and here i want to use the retun values
    }

    struct node log_in()
    {
        ...
        return tmp;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: There's no need to return a global variable from a function. As you're not using the returned value, the function `log_in()` may be defined as `void`.

Comment: You got a point since struct node is a global variable. Possibly this is a remnant of my futile attempts to achieve what i am asking for. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 else if(sel=='2')            //or within this block but I don't know how.
  {  struct node tmp;
     tmp=log_in();
     if (tmp.passlog==TRUE)
     logged_in(tmp.name_log,tmp.user_point);  //and here I want to use the return values
  }
```

and inside the function log_in()

```
struct node log_in()
{ 
 struct tmp
 ...
 return tmp;
}
```

use a local variable inside the function and return this variable. Assign it to another variable inside main().

Comment: Ok my bad I thought i could define a data type locally but its wrong. So i have to declare the type as a global and then use a variable of that type as a local. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the structure first, then create the variable `temp`. Like this:

```
struct node
{
    char name_log[20];
    int passlog;
    int user_point;
};
```

Then you can create the local variable like

```
struct node tmp;
```

Comment: You have to declare the `struct` globally.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a pointer to the `struct node` to your `log_in` function and have it return a boolean value so the caller can check whether logging in succeeded or didn't. (Note I'm trying to guess what you want to achieve, and I might be guessing wrong.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char name_log[20];
    int passlog;
    int user_point;
};

int log_in(char, struct node *);

int log_in(char sel, struct node * tmp) {
    int ret = 0;
    if (sel == '2') {
        ret = 1;
        strcpy( tmp->name_log, "Gonzo" );
        tmp->passlog = 33;
        tmp->user_point = 99;
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    struct node tmp;
    char sel = argv[1][0];
    if ( log_in(sel, &tmp) ) {
        // tmp initialized
        printf( "%s, %d, %d\n", tmp.name_log, tmp.passlog, tmp.user_point );
    }
    else {
        // tmp not initialized
    }
}
```

Call passing `2` on the command line. (If you don't, undefined behaviour.)

Comment: hmm this is still defined as global isnt it?

Comment: The *declaration of the `struct` (so, of the `struct` type)* is accessible globally. The *declaration of the variable (of the `struct` type declared before)* is local to the `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use some struct in 2 different routines - you must declare it outside of both of them since they both have to see how this struct is structured.
BTW - you invoke log_in but do not use its return value.

Comment: yes it still works but the correct declaration is `void log_in()` Fixed that but still cant find a way to make it work with a delcaration of struct within the block of option `else if(sel=='2') {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can't operate on a type that is unknown. If `log_in()` doesn't know the definition of `struct node`, it can't use it directly. The only thing it can do is somehow receive a pointer to a variable of this type and then either treat it as raw data (sequence of bytes) or cast said pointer to a pointer to a known to `log_in()` type and work with that.

You can also redefine `struct node` inside of `log_in()`, which is a way of making `log_in()` operate on a known type:

```
void log_in(void*);
void logged_in(char*, int);

int main(void)
{
    int sel = '2';

    if (sel == '2')
    {
        struct node
        {
            char name_log[20];
            int passlog;
            int user_point;
        } tmp;

        log_in(&tmp);
        if (tmp.passlog)
            logged_in(tmp.name_log, tmp.user_point);
    }

    return 0;
}

void log_in(void* n)
{
    struct node
    {
        char name_log[20];
        int passlog;
        int user_point;
    } *p = n;

    p->passlog = 1;
}

void logged_in(char* name, int point)
{
}
```

If you don't want to pass `tmp` by a formal reference into `log_in()`, you must make it available globally. For example like this:

```
void log_in(void);
void logged_in(char*, int);

void* pTmp;

int main(void)
{
    int sel = '2';

    if (sel == '2')
    {
        struct node
        {
            char name_log[20];
            int passlog;
            int user_point;
        } tmp;

        pTmp = &tmp;
        log_in();
        if (tmp.passlog)
            logged_in(tmp.name_log, tmp.user_point);
    }

    return 0;
}

void log_in(void)
{
    struct node
    {
        char name_log[20];
        int passlog;
        int user_point;
    } *p = pTmp;

    p->passlog = 1;
}

void logged_in(char* name, int point)
{
}
```